# Android inputStream. Checking for newlines and split

Tags: android, split, inputstream, readline

```
            try {
                inputStream = assetManager.open("model.obj");
                if (inputStream != null)
                {
                    Log.d("aaa", "It worked!");

                    //Get length of inputstream
                    for(int i=0;i<inputStream.available();i++)
                    {

                    }
                     //String line = null, input="";

                    /*while( (line = inputStream. ) != null ) 
                    {
                        input += line;
                    }*/
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have inputStream which looks like it is raw bytes where I can get a number of bytes from inputStream and cycle through.
What I actually would like to do is cycle through each line in the file read and split on the space character like split(" ").
Can inputStream be converted into some form more condusive to reading lines and splitting on the space character?

Thank You!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/. try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BufferedReader` class's `readLine()` method as follows to detect the presence of new line.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("file content".getBytes());

//read it with BufferedReader
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
   // perform your task here 
}
```

Comment: I suggest you avoid demonstrating the use of `String.getBytes()` and `new InputStreamReader` without specifying the encoding. It's *always* a good idea to specify the encoding.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
   // perform your task here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Scanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html) class will come in handy for this. You can pass the inputstream to the scanner class and then get them as lines easily.

```
try {
  inputStream = assetManager.open("model.obj");
  Scanner sc;
  if (inputStream != null) {
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream); // also has a constructor which take in a charsetName
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
      sc.nextLine();
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code read file from Assets....

AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

```
try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open("foo.txt");
        if ( inputStream != null)
            Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do not use InputStream is = assetManager.open("assets/foo.txt");

[Try this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) to split stuff that you required...